# What is the correct buildViolation property path when having translatable properties

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony, a2lix-translation

I am not sure, what atPath() parametr to provide in this code:

```
 /**
 * @Assert\Callback
 */
public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context, $payload)
{
    $title = $this->getTitle();
    if ($this->getTitle() !== 'aaa') {
        $context->buildViolation("This title: {$title} sounds totally fake!")
            ->atPath('title')
            ->addViolation();
    }
}
```

$title is abstracted through $translations into another entity.

For a normal property $linkUrl, I just provide 'linkUrl' and it works.

Maybe these html codes can help to decipher it:

This first one, I have problem with. I have tried atPath('translations_cs_title'), but doesn't work.
[image]

This one works with atPath('linkUrl')

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer myself:

translations[cs].title